# Problem in creating table with images using Android Studio with itext pdf

Tags: android, itext

### Problem in creating table with images using Android Studio with itext pdf

I'm creating pdf including tables and images. The problem is that I
 can see images on the first page but cannot see on the second
 page.

- Using `Android Studio 3.1.3` and `itextg-5.5.8`

  ```
  public void createPDF() throws IOException{

      EditText pdfREFNo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etReferenceNo);
      FileName = pdfREFNo.getText().toString()+".pdf";
      outpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PDF/";

      File docsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PDF");
      boolean isPresent = true;
      if (!docsFolder.exists()) {
          isPresent = docsFolder.mkdir();
      }
      if (isPresent) {
          outpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PDF/";
      } else {
      }

      try {
          PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(outpath+FileName));

          Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4,20f,20f,50f,50f);
          Font fontHeader = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 11, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(0, 0, 0));
          Font fontCell = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(0, 0, 0));
          Font fontCell_white = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(255, 255, 255));

          doc.open();

          PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(8);
          table1.setWidthPercentage(100f);

          PdfPTable table_A = new PdfPTable(6);
          table_A.setWidthPercentage(100f);

          // convert image to byte array (arrTick)
          try {
              Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick);
              Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
              arrTick = BMP.getBytes(bitmap);

          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

      //Creating Table 1
      insert_cell(table1,"Table 1 ",Element.ALIGN_LEFT,8,fontHeader,1 ,1, false, emptyArr, -1);

      insert_cell(table1, "Yes", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 2, fontCell, 0 ,1, false, emptyArr, -1);
      insert_cell(table1, "No", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 2, fontCell, 0 ,1, false, emptyArr, -1);
      insert_cell(table1, "Uncertain", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 4, fontCell, 0 ,1, false, emptyArr, -1);

      if (cbYes.isChecked() == true) {
          insert_cell(table1, "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 2, fontCell, 0, 1, true, arrTick, 3);
      } else {
          insert_cell(table1, "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 2, fontCell_white, 0, 1, false, emptyArr, -1);
      }
      if (cbNo.isChecked() == true) {
          insert_cell(table1, "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 2, fontCell, 0, 1, true, arrTick, 3);
      } else {
          insert_cell(table1, "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 2, fontCell_white, 0, 1, false, emptyArr, -1);
      }
      if (cbUncertain.isChecked() == true) {
          insert_cell(table1, "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 4, fontCell, 0, 1, true, arrTick, 3);
      } else {
          insert_cell(table1, "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 4, fontCell_white, 0, 1, false, emptyArr, -1);
      }
      doc.add(table1);
      doc.newPage();

      insert_cell(table_A,"Remark",Element.ALIGN_LEFT,6,fontHeader,1 ,1, false, emptyArr, -1);
      insert_cell(table_A, etRemarks.getText().toString(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 6, fontCell, 0 ,1, false, emptyArr, -1);
      insert_cell(table_A," ",Element.ALIGN_LEFT,6,fontCell_white,0 ,0, false, emptyArr, -1);

      insert_cell(table_A,"table_A",Element.ALIGN_LEFT,6,fontHeader,1 ,1, false, emptyArr, -1);

      insert_cell(table_A, "Yes", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 2, fontCell, 0 ,1, false, emptyArr, -1);
      insert_cell(table_A, "No", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 2, fontCell, 0 ,1, false, emptyArr, -1);
      insert_cell(table_A, "Pending", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 2, fontCell, 0 ,1, false, emptyArr, -1);

      if (cbYes2.isChecked()) {
          insert_cell(table_A, "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 2, fontCell, 0, 1, true, arrTick, 3);
      } else {
          insert_cell(table_A, "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 2, fontCell_white, 0, 1, false, emptyArr, -1);
      }

      if (cbNo2.isChecked()) {
          insert_cell(table_A, "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 2, fontCell, 0, 1, true, arrTick, 3);
      } else {
          insert_cell(table_A, "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 2, fontCell_white, 0, 1, false, emptyArr, -1);
      }

      if (cbUncertain.isChecked()) {
          insert_cell(table_A, "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 2, fontCell, 0, 1, true, arrTick, 3);
      } else {
          insert_cell(table_A, "", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 2, fontCell_white, 0, 1, false, emptyArr, -1);
      }

      doc.add(table_A);
      doc.close();

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
      {
      e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (DocumentException e)
      {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  private void insert_cell(PdfPTable table, String text, int align, int colspan, Font font, int background, int border, boolean signFlag, byte[] sign, int type) throws IOException, BadElementException {

      if(text.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") == false && signFlag == false) {
          PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text.trim(), font));
          cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
          cell.setColspan(colspan);
          cell.setPaddingLeft(5f);
          cell.setPaddingTop(3f);
          cell.setPaddingBottom(3f);
          cell.setPaddingRight(5f);

          if (background == 0) {
              cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
          } else if (background == 1) {
              cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
          } else if (background == 2) {
              cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
          }else if (background == 3) {
              cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.YELLOW);
          }

          if (border == 0) {
              cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
          } else if (border == 1) {
              cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.BOX);
          }
          table.addCell(cell);
      }

  // to add empty cell

      if (text.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") == true && signFlag == false) {
          PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("-", font));
          cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
          cell.setColspan(colspan);
          cell.setPaddingLeft(5f);
          cell.setPaddingTop(3f);
          cell.setPaddingBottom(3f);
          cell.setPaddingRight(5f);

          if (background == 0) {
              cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
          } else if (background == 1) {
              cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
          } else if (background == 2) {
              cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
          }else if (background == 3) {
              cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.YELLOW);
          }

          if (border == 0) {
              cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
          } else if (border == 1) {
              cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.BOX);
          }
          table.addCell(cell);
      }

  // to add image

  if(text.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") ==true && signFlag == true && sign != null)
  {
      Bitmap img1 = BMP.getImage(sign);
      Drawable d1 = new BitmapDrawable(img1);
      BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d1);
      Bitmap bmp = bitDw.getBitmap();
      ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
      Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

      switch (type)
      {
      case 1:     // signature
      try{
          image.scaleAbsolute(150f,70f);
          PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
          cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
          cell.setColspan(colspan);
          cell.addElement(image);
          table.addCell(cell);

      }catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      break;

      case 2:     // photo
      try{
          image.setRotationDegrees(270f);
          PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
         cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
          cell.setColspan(colspan);
          cell.addElement(image);
          table.addCell(cell);

      }catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      break;

      case 3:     // tick
      try{
          image.scaleAbsolute(100f,18f);
          image.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
          PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
          cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
          cell.setColspan(colspan);
          cell.addElement(image);
          table.addCell(cell);
      }catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      break;
  }
  }
  ```

[image: Error in table cell with image]

I'm creating pdf including tables and images. The problem is that I
 can see images on the first page but cannot see on the second
 page.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using Image.getInstance(byte[] sign).

```
case 3:     // tick
    try{
        Image tick = Image.getInstance(sign);   // byte[] sign
        tick.scaleAbsolute(100f,18f);
        tick.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
        cell.setColspan(colspan);
        cell.addElement(tick);
        table.addCell(cell);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    break;
```

Instead of:

```
Bitmap img1 = BMP.getImage(sign);
Drawable d1 = new BitmapDrawable(img1);
BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d1);
Bitmap bmp = bitDw.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

case 3:     // tick
    try{
        image.scaleAbsolute(100f,18f);
        image.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
        cell.setColspan(colspan);
        cell.addElement(image);
        table.addCell(cell);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    break;
```

Fixed PDF:

[image: Fixed PDF]